# iOS Charts - How to set different color of exact vertical grid line than have others

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

In my application I'm using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and I want to split my line chart to sectors by vertical grid line with different color than have others (someting like on chart below). I looked into documentation but I didn't find any solution how to do that. I know only how to change color of all grid lines at once. Thanks for any advice.

[image: example chart]

**UPDATE:**

Here is my solution. I have array with x positions for vertical lines and in for loop I will add limit lines to chart.

```
for k:Int in 0 ..< limitLines.count {

        let limitLine = ChartLimitLine()
        limitLine.lineColor = UIColor.red
        limitLine.limit = limitLines[k]
        limitLine.lineWidth = 0.8
        lineChartView.xAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine)

 }
```

Here is resulting chart.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well.. this is not officially supported, but you could override `drawGridLine()` on x axis to do so, just need to know which grid line needs another color.